# TypeError: update_graph_scatter() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, plotly-dash

**TypeError: update_graph_scatter() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
[image]
Getting the above error while using dash with python.
Below is my code.**

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import requests

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Iframe(src = 'https://www.flightradar24.com', height = 500, width = 1200)
    ]),

    html.Div([
    html.Pre(
        id='counter_text',
        children='Active flights worldwide:'
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph',style={'width':1200}),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=6000, # 6000 milliseconds = 6 seconds
        n_intervals=0
    )])
])
counter_list = []

@app.callback(Output('counter_text', 'children'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
@staticmethod
def update_layout(n):
    url = "https://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?faa=1\
           &mlat=1&flarm=1&adsb=1&gnd=1&air=1&vehicles=1&estimated=1&stats=1"
    # A fake header is necessary to access the site:
    res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    data = res.json()
    counter = 0
    for element in data["stats"]["total"]:
        counter += data["stats"]["total"][element]
    counter_list.append(counter)
    return 'Active flights worldwide: {}'.format(counter)

@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph','figure'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_graph(n):
    fig = go.Figure(
        data = [go.Scatter(
        x = list(range(len(counter_list))),
        y = counter_list,
        mode='lines+markers'
        )])
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

### **As you can see in the browser i am getting this issue.**

---

---

Please help as
i have tried every solution to no avail

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the decorator, `@staticmethod`, here:

```py
@app.callback(Output('counter_text', 'children'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
@staticmethod
def update_layout(n):
    url = "https://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?faa=1\
           &mlat=1&flarm=1&adsb=1&gnd=1&air=1&vehicles=1&estimated=1&stats=1"
```

This is a normal function, not a method of a class, so the `@staticmethod` decorator is incorrect here. I removed that, and your app worked nicely.